# How can I sort an array of fractions of type (int n, int d)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reduce

public class Fraction {

```
private int num, den;
static double ratio;

public Fraction() {
    super();
    num = 1;
    den = 1;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Fraction(int num, int den) {
    super();
    this.num = num;
    this.den = den;

}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}

public int getDen() {
    return den;
}

public double getRatio() {
    return ratio;
}

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public void setDen(int den) {
    this.den = den;
}

public void setRatio(double ratio) {
    Fraction.ratio = ratio;
}

public Fraction add(Fraction second)
{
    Fraction third = new Fraction();
    third.num = this.num * second.den + this.den * second.num;
    third.den = this.den * second.den;
    return third;
}

public double findratio(double n, double d)
{
    ratio = 0;

    ratio = n/d;

    return ratio;
}

public int findGCD (int n, int d)
{
    int gcd = 0, temp = 0;

    while (n != 0 && d != 0)
    {
        temp = n;
        n = d % n;
        d = temp;
    }

    gcd = n + d;
    return gcd;
}

public void reduce()
{
    int gcd = findGCD(num, den);
    {
        this.num /= gcd;
        this.den /= gcd;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return num + "/" + den;
}
```

}

import java.util.*;

public class testFraction {

```
private static Fraction frac;
Fraction[] fracs = new Fraction[8];

public static void fillArray()
{
    Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    Fraction[] fracs = new Fraction[8];


    for(int i = 0; i < fracs.length - 1; i++)
    {
        Fraction addt = new Fraction();
        Fraction f = new Fraction();
        fracs[i] = f;
        testFraction.frac = f;
        f.setNum(z.nextInt());
        f.setDen(k.nextInt());

        addt = f.add(fracs[i]);


    }
        System.out.println(frac);
        Arrays.sort(fracs);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fracs));

    z.close();
    k.close();

}




public static void main(String[] args) {

    fillArray();



}
```

}

I have a Fraction class that defines GCD, addition, and reduction of fractions, but i am getting stuck trying to use these methods with an array of fractions.  Additionally, i need to sort this array from smallest to largest, remove the smallest and largest, then add the rest together and reduce.

Does anyone have any tips that might get me on the right track?

Comment: Use their floating point (i.e float, double) representation to compare them.

Comment: Assuming all denominators are positive, you can compare `a/b` and `c/d` by comparing `ad` and `bc` (multiply both sides by `bd` to see this).  To find out how to write a comparator and use it for sorting, see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/3137/comparable-and-comparator/10693/sorting-a-list-using-comparablet-or-a-comparatort#t=201612180346068842778.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this boils down to implementing a compare or compareTo method as per the `Comparator<Fraction>` or `Comparable<Fraction>` interfaces.

Comparing the ratios of two `Fraction` objects would be a way<sup>1</sup> to implement a sensible ordering ... assuming that the ratio has been computed correctly.  If you want to treat `Fraction(1, 2)` and `Fraction(2, 4)` as unequal, then you could use the value of (say) `num` as a "tie breaker" when the ratios are the same.

Once `Fraction` implements `Comparable<Fraction>` or you have implemented a separate `Comparator<Fraction>` class / instance, then a call to `Arrays.sort(Fraction[])` will work.

---

There are problems with the way your code is currently dealing with the ratio.  Surely, it should NOT be a `static` field, and you should NOT be able to set it.  Surely, it is *derived* information, and should (only / always) be computed from the `num` and `den` fields.

Indeed, it would be better overall if a `Fraction` was designed to be *immutable*, with `final` fields and no setter methods.

---

<sup>1. With `num` and `den` are `int` and `ratio` as a `double`, there should be enough precision to represent the ratio with sufficient accuracy.  If `num` and `den` were `long` instead, the `ratio` would not have sufficient precision for the ordering to work in all cases.</sup>